# Spring Boot - multiple datasource configuration

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have below application.properties in my application for configuring two datasources and my Spring boot version is 2.1.3.RELEASE

```
spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
spring.datasource2.username=//username
spring.datasource2.password=//pwd

spring.datasource1.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2
spring.datasource1.username=//username
spring.datasource1.password=//pwd
spring.datasource1.initialization-mode=always

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

I get the following error

```
ContextLoader:296 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3970 ms
 [main] WARN  AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:557 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-12-04 20:47:27 [main] INFO  StandardService:173 - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-04 20:47:27 [main] INFO  ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener:142 - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-04 20:47:27 [main] ERROR LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:42 - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

What I tried so far:

```
 Disabling DatasourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJPAAutoCOnfiguration.class, TransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class
```

It did not work.

How do I resolve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in the error, spring needs url. During Spring boot initialization, spring will look for this property `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres`

You are using few properties which don't exist in the spring boot properties.

```
spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
spring.datasource2.username=//username
spring.datasource2.password=//pwd

spring.datasource1.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2
spring.datasource1.username=//username
spring.datasource1.password=//pwd
```

If you want to use multiple datasources, you have to programmatically create.

you can refer below links : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases